# Permission denied when creating directory

Tags: rust, directory, path

So I would like to create a directory in `$HOME` but then it says permisson denied, how does creating directories in `$HOME` require permissions?

Here's the code

```rs
let mut dir = home::home_dir().expect("Cannot get your home directory"); // Go to the home directory

dbg!(&dir);

dir.push("/.siriusmart");

if !dir.exists() { // Create a directory if it doesn't exist
    fs::create_dir(&dir)?;
}
```

Here's the output

```rs
[src/main.rs:122] &dir = "/home/siriusmart"
Error: Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include the leading `/` in the directory name. This is interpreted as replacing the entire path from root.

If you move the `dbg!` statement to after the `push`, then you'd see the directory was  `/.siriusmart` instead of `/your/home/director/.siriusmart` as you may have expected.

So just do:

```
dir.push(".siriusmart");
```